# PHP & Jquery Image crop and upload

Tags: php, jquery

When a user uploads a picture, pop up window should come, where he'll crop the image, after this is done. I want to use php script to upload this to folder but i want cropped image and thumbnail of cropped image to be present.After cropping is done,then he'll click upload button which will upload cropped image then create thumbnail of it and upload them to a folders.

I tried many plug-ins but could not find one for my requirement.

Plug-ins that i tried are http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-jquery-image-cropping-plug-in-from-scratch-part-ii/

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why doesn't Jcrop that you suggested meets your requirements? I've browsed through the site and found everything you need. [Thumbnail preview](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail) / [Crop in PHP](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop)

Comment: @Alvin Wong:User has to first select the image ,next he should be able to crop then only it has to get uploaded,i do not find that there.if you can find,share the link.

Comment: can't crop the image file in javascript, has to be done at server. Image has to be uploaded first before it can even be inserted in browser. After upload user would set size and server would have to crop to size based on position and size

Comment: @charlietfl:When you mean upload will it get upload to a folder or just in the browser.

Comment: @charlietfl:Three images would be there.Original image,cropped image then thumbnail for cropped image right.

Comment: you could delete the original

Comment: @charlietfl:In jcrop,thereis no upload button and i can not even crop when i downloaded their source code,can you point out a good one which does even upload thing in PHP script.

Comment: I doubt you will find a complete package that does everything you want, you will have to build a lot of it yourself. At least as far as setting up the uploader, file management etc

Comment: @charlietfl:If the crop thing work's,i can upload them to folder using PHP script.

Comment: As charlietfl says, it's quite difficult to find something that fits 100% of your requirements. In web development you have to tweak constantly, and many times you have to build almost everything by yourself (it's when you can share with the community, and this is the way new projects appear).

Comment: You can find a good and new jQuery and PHP script here:
[jQuery image upload and crop script](http://www.ephespage.de/artikel/detail/a/n/si/ch/t/jquery-image-upload-and-crop-script-with-preview-and-resizing.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple tutorial for image crop and replace
First create view file for select image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cropsetup.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="jc-demo-box">
 <img src="uploads/Chrysanthemum.jpg" id="target" alt="[Jcrop Example]" />
  <div id="form-container">
  <form id="cropimg" name="cropimg" method="post" action="crop.php" target="_blank">
          <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x">
          <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y">
          <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w">
          <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h">
          <input type="hidden" id="image_name" name="image_name" value="uploads/Chrysanthemum.jpg">
          <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Crop Image!">
  </form>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then create image crop php file

```
    <?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$targ_w =$_POST['w'];
$targ_h =$_POST['h'];

$jpeg_quality = 90;

if(!isset($_POST['x']) || !is_numeric($_POST['x'])) {
  die('Please select a crop area.');
}

$src = $_POST['image_name'];
$system = explode(".", $src);

if (preg_match("/jpg|jpeg/", $system[1]))
{
    $src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}
if (preg_match("/png/", $system[1]))
{
    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
}
if (preg_match("/gif/", $system[1]))
{
    $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
}

$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($targ_w, $targ_h);

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$src_img,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

if (preg_match("/png/", $system[1]))
{
    imagepng($dst_r, $_POST['image_name']); 
} 
else if (preg_match("/gif/", $system[1]))
{
    imagegif($dst_r, $_POST['image_name']);
}
else
{
    imagejpeg($dst_r, $_POST['image_name']); 
}

imagedestroy($dst_r);   
imagedestroy($src_img);

exit;
   }

  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks , How we can access "jquery.Jcrop.js" , "cropsetup.js" files ?

Comment: @Samad. You can download from this link

https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/dynamic-jquery-image-avatar-cropping-effect