# Crop Image and upload with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, cropperjs

I have a crop image script. How can the script upload the cropped image when the user clicks the save button? How can I make the PHP the cropped image and upload to server?

The documentation is here on [github - cropperjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Cropper.js</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/cropper.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.1/cropper.css" />
  
  <style>
    .container {
      max-width: 640px;
      margin: 20px auto;
    }

    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Cropper with a range of aspect ratio</h1>
 
    <div>
      <img id="image" src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/images/picture.jpg" alt="Picture">
    </div>
 <button onclick="cropper.getCroppedCanvas()">Save</button>
  </div>

  <!-- <script src="dist/cropper.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.1/cropper.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var image = document.querySelector('#image');
      var minAspectRatio = 1.0;
      var maxAspectRatio = 1.0;
      var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        ready: function () {
          var cropper = this.cropper;
          var containerData = cropper.getContainerData();
          var cropBoxData = cropper.getCropBoxData();
          var aspectRatio = cropBoxData.width / cropBoxData.height;
          var newCropBoxWidth;

          if (aspectRatio < minAspectRatio || aspectRatio > maxAspectRatio) {
            newCropBoxWidth = cropBoxData.height * ((minAspectRatio + maxAspectRatio) / 2);

            cropper.setCropBoxData({
              left: (containerData.width - newCropBoxWidth) / 2,
              width: newCropBoxWidth
            });
          }
        },
        cropmove: function () {
          var cropper = this.cropper;
          var cropBoxData = cropper.getCropBoxData();
          var aspectRatio = cropBoxData.width / cropBoxData.height;

          if (aspectRatio < minAspectRatio) {
            cropper.setCropBoxData({
              width: cropBoxData.height * minAspectRatio
            });
          } else if (aspectRatio > maxAspectRatio) {
            cropper.setCropBoxData({
              width: cropBoxData.height * maxAspectRatio
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- FULL DOCUMENTATION ON https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs -->
  <!-- My question is: How do i get the cropped image and upload via php ? -->
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this . i have faced this and it is tested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132841/php-jquery-image-crop-and-upload/23787221#23787221

Comment: It's another script, I would like to do this using this script https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *how to crop and upload when click save button? , How to make the php get the cropped image and upload to server?*

In [the readme](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs), the description of method [`getCroppedCanvas()`](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#user-content-getcroppedcanvasoptions) mentions uploading a cropped image:

> <sub>After then, you can display the canvas as an image directly, or use [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to get a Data URL, or use [HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) to get a blob and upload it to server with FormData if the browser supports these APIs.</sub><sup>[1](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#user-content-getcroppedcanvasoptions)</sup>
>
> ```
> cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
>   var formData = new FormData();
>
>   formData.append('croppedImage', blob);
>
>   // Use `jQuery.ajax` method
>   $.ajax('/path/to/upload', {
>     method: "POST",
>     data: formData,
>     processData: false,
>     contentType: false,
>     success: function () {
>       console.log('Upload success');
>     },
>     error: function () {
>       console.log('Upload error');
>     }
>   });
> });
> ```

So for your example, the button labeled *save* references *cropper* but that is only defined inside the callback of the DOM-loaded callback (i.e. `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {`). I would recommend using an event delegate (see example plunker mentioned below) but if you wanted to reference *cropper* it would need to be declared outside the DOM-loaded callback.

```
var cropper;
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    //assign cropper:
    cropper = new Cropper(image, { ...
```

You can see it in action in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xuIMTKRhDvBmJiMorvTg). It utilizes a PHP code that merely takes the uploaded cropped image and returns the base64 encoded version (using [base64_encode()](http://php.net/base64_encode)).

The PHP code used in the plunker example is listed below:

```
<?php
$output = array();

if(isset($_FILES) && is_array($_FILES) && count($_FILES)) {
     $output['FILES'] = $_FILES;

     //this is where the cropped image could be saved on the server
     $output['uploaded'] = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['croppedImage']['tmp_name']));
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
```

Instead of just echoing the base64-encoded version of the file, [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) could be used to upload the file and then return information about the uploaded file (e.g. file ID, path, etc).

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['croppedImage']['tmp_name'], '/path/to/save/cropped/image');
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>(https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#user-content-getcroppedcanvasoptions)</sub>

Comment: I will do that!

Comment: I used your code but to have correct file I had to remove base64_encode function.